# AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor not rendering content

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have two IIS on different servers. A web page containing AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor has been hosted on both servers. One server is displaying content of AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor body while another server is not. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Check the server logs

Comment: Did you check the browser console to see if any errors are logged there?